# Workroom synonyms?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I searched for synonyms of *workroom* but dict.cc just offers *working room* or *study room*. I think *working room* is inadequate for avoiding repetitions, because it is pretty much the same and I suspect that *study room* is not really the same as a *workroom*?!

Additionally I was really disappointed by oxforddictionaries.com not finding a single synonym for *workroom*.

Any suggestions?

I have several places in my text where workrooms are mentioned. The text is about the distribution (or better allocation?) of workrooms to the staff of a university.

**Edit:** Please feel free to correct any mistakes in my text above as I am highly interested in learning english as well as possible (:

Comment: Can you offer any details whatsoever on what you're trying to say? Diction and word choice rely primarily on context, and you have provided none. "Workroom" is a very generic word that really doesn't mean anything outside of context, because all jobs require different tools to be done; some don't need any. It is designed to be generic, since it is just a compound noun of two nouns that are themselves not very descriptive. It seems like you're looking for a different word?

Answer (score 1):

From [google search](https://www.google.com.hk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=work%20shop%20definition):

> **WORKSHOP**
>
> 2. : **workroom**.

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/workshop):

> 1. a **room**, group of **rooms**, or building in which work, especially mechanical work, is carried on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain on the exact setting of your "workrooms", so pay close attention to the definitions.

---

You might consider:

- **study** (without "room")

> a room used or designed for reading, writing, or academic work

This is usually a room within somebody's house.

- **common room**

> **chiefly Brit.**
>   a room in a school or college for use of students or staff outside teaching hours.

This is also a relaxation area, it's not specifically designed for work.

- **office**

> a room, set of rooms, or building used as a place of business for non-manual work

This can also refer to a specific room inside somebody's house.

- **lab** or **laboratory**

Depending on the setting, this might be suitable. While I was at university studying computer science, we often did our work in the "computer lab", but it's worth noting that I can't find a definition to match.

- **workstation**, also simply **station**

> 1 a desktop computer terminal, typically networked and more powerful than a personal computer.
>   2 an area where work of a particular nature is carried out, such as a specific location on an assembly line.

This tends to refer to a small working space. It might be a single desk in a larger work room.

---

<sub>These definitions were taken from Apple's built-in dictionary on Mac. I'm not sure how to reference them.</sub>